# MVVM DataBinding

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm

I've started an MVVM project and now I'm stucking with correct DataBinding.
My project has:

A UserControl whit a ViewModel as DataContext like:

```
public partial class TestUserControl: UserControl
{
   public TestUserControl()
   {
       this.DataContext = new TestUserControlViewModel();
   }
}
```

ViewModel code is (BaseViewModel class contains PropertyChangedEventHandler):

```
public class TestUserControlViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   public KrankenkasseControlViewModel()
   {}

   public IEnumerable<DataItem> GetAllData
   {
      get
      {
          IGetTheData src= new DataRepository();
          return src.GetData();
      }
   }
}
```

IGetTheData is the interface to DataContext:

```
public interface IGetTheData
{
   IEnumerable<DataItem> GetData();
}
```

}

and finally the DataRepository code:

```
public class DataRepository : IGetTheData
{
   private TestProjectDataContext dax = new TestProjectDataContext();

   public IEnumerable<DataItem> GetData()
   {
       return (from d in this.dax.TestData
               select new DataItem
               {
                  ID = d.ID,
                  SomeOtherData = d.SomeOtherData
               });
   }
}
```

My UserControl has a few TextBoxes, but what's the best way to bind correctly?

Thanks for your help, regards.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all answers. Maybe I wrote too less and some code above is wrong for my propose, but I have several textboxes which should be filled from database and user should be able to type in some text which will be saved back to database, so using listbox/listview is useless for me. I've thought it's able to retrieve all items from database to DataItem and then binding each property to textboxes. But still don't know how it could work. Regards

Comment: You should update your question to reflect your real requirements better. Always remember that in future other people with an equal problem will be happy to find your question and the answers; this works only if the question is properly formulated.

Comment: I edited my answer, but regardless of whether that was what you wanted to know, edit your question for better understanding in future! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: Binding the data against multiple textboxes**

After reading your comment, I will elaborate my example for textboxes.

First important thing is that the ViewModel will model the things in the View, so that the View gets all information it needs *in the structure* it needs. That means, if you have multiple textboses in the View, you will need multiple string Properties in your ViewModel, one for each textbox.

In your XAML you could have something like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ID, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeOtherData, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and in your ViewModel

```
public class TestUserControlViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    private string id;
    private string someOtherData;

    public TestUserControlViewModel() {
        DataItem firstItem = new DataRepository().GetData().First();
        this.ID = firstItem.ID;
        this.SomeOtherData = firstItem.SomeOtherData;
    }

    public string ID {
        get {
            return this.id;
        }
        set {
            if (this.id == value) return;
            this.id = value;
            this.OnPropertyChangedEvent("ID");
        }
    }

    public string SomeOtherData {
        get {
            return this.someOtherData;
        }
        set {
            if (this.someOtherData == value) return;
            this.someOtherData = value;
            this.OnPropertyChangedEvent("SomeOtherData");
        }
    }
}
```

Here I assume that in your `BaseViewModel` there is an `OnPropertyChangedEvent` method to fire the corresponding event. This tells the View that the property has changed and it must update itself.

Note the `Mode=TwoWay` in the XAML. This means, that it doesn't matter on which side the value changes, the other side will reflect the change immediately. So if the user changes a value in a `TwoWay` bound `TextBox`, then the corresponding ViewModel property will automatically change! And also vice versa: if you change the ViewModel property programmatically, the View will refresh.

If you want to show multiple textboxes for more than one data item, then you must introduce more Properties in the ViewModel and bind them accordingly. Maybe a `ListBox` with a flexible number of `TextBox`es inside is a solution then, like @Haspemulator already answered.

**Binding the data against a collection control**

In the `TestUserControl` I guess you have a control (like a `ListView`) to show the list of loaded things. So bind that control against the list in the ViewModel with

```
<ListView ... ItemsSource="{Binding GetAllData}" ... />
```

First you must understand that *Binding* means not "read the data and then forget the ViewModel". Instead you bind the View to the ViewModel (and its Properties) as long as the View lasts. From this point of view, `AllData` is a much better name than `GetAllData` (thanks @Malcolm O'Hare).

Now in your code, every time the View reads the `AllData` property, a new `DataRepository` is created. Because of the Binding, that is not what you want, instead you want to have one instance of `DataRepository` for the whole lifetime of the View, which is used to read the initial data and can later be used to update the View, if the underlying database changes (maybe with an event).

To enable such a behavior you should change the type of the `AllData` property to an `ObservableCollection`, so that the View can automatically update the list if changes occur.

```
public class TestUserControlViewModel : BaseViewModel
    private ObservableCollection<DataItem> allData;

    public TestUserControlViewModel() {
         IGetTheData src = new DataRepository();
         this.allData = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>(src.GetData());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DataItem> AllData {
        get {
            return this.allData;
        }
    }

    public void AddDataItem(DataItem item) {
        this.allData.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Now if you call `AddDataItem` later, the ListView will update itself automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Your Property Name is bad.  You should call it AllData, not GetAllData.

Since you are returning a collection, you probably should be using some sort of list control (ListBox, ListView).

In that case you'd be doing

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GetAllData}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Guten Abend. :) As it already mentioned, since you're returning the collection, it's better to use a ListBox. The comment about having ObservableCollection as a cache is also absolutely valid. I would add that if you need to have your data editable, you should use TextBox inside the ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text={Binding SomeOtherData,Mode=TwoWay} />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

In this case if user edits the text in the box, data will be updated in your data object, so that it could be saved in the database later.